# Is there a command line tool to copy files to a specific directory on multiple remote computers?

Tags: command-line-arguments

Is there a command line tool to copy files to a specific directory on multiple remote computers.  The path is from C:\temp\text.txt to c:\users\first.last\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\  . The problem I am having it that there is a space in the \start menu\ that will not allow (what I have tried) a CP or copy command to get past that point.  I tried to use the method of \start~1\ which failed.  any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the only problem is the space in the path quotation should be your friend.
"c:\users\first.last\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup\"
as target should do the trick.
I am not a windows user so make sure to double check it.

Comment: That worked!!!   Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using quotes in your arguments ensures that the right path is used.

Just use "c:\users\first.last\appdata\roaming\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\startup" as your second argument.